# How to search in data table using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Data table result in grid:

```
SerialNumber  PartNumber   
000000001     QWERTY
000000002     QERTY
```

I need to search a particular SerialNumber in the result of my data table using a Textbox control.

Pseudocode example:

```
If
    SearctTexbox.Text =000000001 
    Message: This Serial is Ok!

Else
    Message: Not Ok
```

How to do this in LINQ or any other methods?

Comment: Why are you using a `DataTable` with LINQ? Next you'll want to use "horse shoes" with "fuel injection", or "leeches" with "nuclear medicine". ;-)

Comment: :) Yeah..I need to query a data table using linq so i dont need to create another SQL selects..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SerialNumber column have unique values, so give it a try:

```
//dt is DataTable
dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[1] { dt.Columns[0] };  // set your primary key
DataRow dRow = dt.Rows.Find(SearchTextbox.Text);
if (dRow != null){
     // you've found it
}
else{
    //sorry dude
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need LINQ? You can try with

```
dataTable.Select("condition");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string massage = dc.Parts.Select(
    o => o.SerialNumber == SearctTexbox.Text).Count()>0 ? "Found it"!"No Find";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var item = from r in Datatable.AsEnumerable()
            where r.Field<int>("SerialNumber") == int.Parse(SearchTextbox.Text.ToString())
            select r.Field<int>("SerialNumber");

if (item == null)
{
   // not found
}
else
{
   // you found it. 
}
```